# What was the original Torah based on?

Tags: torah-study, mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism

B”H

There’s halacha that every Sofer who is writing a Torah must write it “based” on another Kosher Torah, by reading each word, saying it out loud from the other Torah, then writing it.

When it comes to the first physical Torah Moshe wrote, it makes sense to say that he read it based off of the spiritual Torah that was written with black fire on white fire since before the creation of the universe, but:

What was the *original * Torah (written with black fire on white fire) written from?

Comment: Ana Nafshis Ketovis Yehovis. Shabbat 105a

Comment: As far as I remember, Reb Tzadok says that the black writing in the original Torah is a *tzimtzum*. I.e. the original Torah wasn't written, it was unwritten. I.e. the black fire is the *tzimtzum* that allows *olam hazeh* to exist. But relative to us it's a *giluy*, because it is our connection to *ein sof*.

Comment: Do you realize that it is logically impossible for every Torah to be written from a prior one? One Torah must have been written a priori.

Comment: @N.T. the Torah existed since before the Universe. Are you aware that the universe was created from the Torah?

Comment: @TheGRAPKE interesting. Does it say there which tzimtzum it refers to? Even before what people call “tzimtzum harishon” there were many tzimtzumim within the Ohr Ein Sof itself. In terms of the Sefiros what specifically is referred to by the black fire? If we knew that we can look In Chassidus and Kabbalah for how that level came to be etc.

Comment: @YaakovYitzchakbenMoshe See Toldos Aharon beginning of Vayikra.

Comment: Very aware, trust me. Nevertheless, G-d must have created the first Torah from nothing.

Comment: In addition, the Gemara says Rebbe Meir once wrote a Megillah when he did not have a prior one so he could read it on Purim. The Gemara says this was okay because Rebbe Meir was an expert. Hashem is also an expert.